# Build the OpenCV 2.0 libraries from source using Visual Studio 2010 Beta and CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cmake

OpenCV 2.0a does not include pre-compiled OpenCV libraries for Visual Studio users. I am trying to build the libraries from source using Visual Studio 2010 Beta and CMake, but I am getting lot of errors.
I even tried generating the libs from dlls using dumpbin but the linker errors are still persisting. Please guide me to generate the static libs for VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

If the build error you're seeing is related to:

```
'back_inserter': identifier not found
```

as is likely the case for the source files `cvmodelest.cpp` and `cvhog.cpp`, add the following include statement to each of those source files:

```
#include <iterator>
```

For more info about the `'back_inserter': identifier not found error`, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/25/stl-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx).

Comment: Of the various blog posts and other pages about using CMake, I found this one helpful:

http://electronic-salad.blogspot.com/2010/03/install-opencv20-for-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Try <strike>[this tutorial](http://uowteaminvincible.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/getting-started-with-opencv-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-in-windows-vista/)</strike>(dead) and [this one](http://www.aishack.in/2010/03/installing-and-configuring-opencv-2-0-on-windows/) out as well.

I tried this with VS 2010 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of late, but I created a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBhwbRoKvk) for compiling and configuring OpenCV 2.1 with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

See [another StackOverflow thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32)  It's for VC++ 2008, but it may help.