# How to install OpenCV 2.0 on win32

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, opencv, projects-and-solutions

I need to install OpenCV on Win32. I do not have it installed currently. I downloaded OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.exe and ran it.  What the heck do I do now?  There are no .lib's and whatnot.

I found some instructions for building the release using cmake at  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide .  I downloaded the latest and greatest cmake, and tried to follow the instructions, but I was guessing. No joy.

I specified VC++9 when I did the "configure," but cmake built a VC++ 6 dsw file.  No vcproj.  I converted the dsw into a vc++9 vcproj anyway, just to see if it would work.  Nope. It compiled lots of files, but many failed because it could not find omp.h.  Sure enough, it's not there, anywhere. The build log said, 'A tool returned an error code from "Performing Custom Build Step".'

I am lost.

Ideally, I would like to find a full installation with all the files pre-built for Win32 vc++ 2008.  Failing that, I need instructions that even I can follow.  Short sentences and small words, but lots of them.

Please help!

UPDATE: I tried to build just CXCORE.  It complained, "cannot open file 'VCOMPD.lib'"  There's that OMP again.

Comment: Let me make your life MUCH MUCH easier. Abandon OpenCV and use EmguCV instead. Easier to install, easier to use in Visual Studio, and easier to debug. Additionally any apps you make with EmguCV will be much more distributable as they will be based in .NET, thus much easier to run on Windows and Linux (in Mono).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For version 2.0, you must build the project from source.

Here's what you will need:

1. [The OpenCV installer.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.0/)
2. CMake. [Here's the CMake installer.](http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.0-win32-x86.exe)
3. [Instructions for using CMake](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/2.0/OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.Readme.Please.txt) to install OpenCV-2.0.01-win32.  Those instructions need an **extra step** if you are using a **vc++ Express** edition.  In that case you must ***un*-check** ENABLE_OPENMP when running the CMake GUI.
4. [Instructions for setting up an application project.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B) (Thanks to mloskot for this find.)

Comment: For a video guide, check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBhwbRoKvk (compiles OpenCV 2.1 with TBB support for Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed `OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.exe` then it will install pre-built DLLs and libs. Then you just have to follow the instructions [in this tutorial](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B).

I recommend that you wipe the folder you previously installed OpenCV2.0 in and reinstall it.

**Update:**

Well sorry it didn't work out. I suggest the following then: check out the latest version from the SVN repository, https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv with any SVN client - I use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads).

Then run CMake (I see you've already installed it) on the source folder and then compile the Solution file. This **should** work - it does for me.

I apologize for my old answer - I had started off with OpenCV a few months ago in the same way and assumed that downloading the Gold version would still work - apparently not.

**OMP**

The OMP issue may arise from the checked **Enable OpenMP** in the CMake config. Try unchecking that .. might solve your initial problem.

Comment: I did as you said, up to a point.  I had to stop where it said to put "C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cv\include" into the INCLUDE directories list.  There is no such directory. Actually, I took the default and installed it in C:\OpenCV2.0.  But there is no cv directory there either. Also, there is no cv.lib anywhere.

Comment: I did it again.  I ran the uninstall.exe, which completely emptied the installation directory.  I removed the directory.  I went to the registry and found two keys for OpenCV and removed them.  I re-installed.  Still no cv/include or other include directories specified.  Still no cv.lib anywhere.

Comment: I found this: 2. Due to many technical problems the installation package does
   not include pre-compiled OpenCV libraries for Visual Studio users.

   Instead, it includes libraries built with MinGW 4.3.3 TDM-SJLJ.

   They are good enough to run the C/C++ and Python samples and tests,
   but for developing your OpenCV-based applications using
   Visual Studio, Borland IDE etc., or even a different version of MinGW,
   you need to build the libraries with your compiler using CMake,
   as explained here:
      http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide.
   
  So I am back to that.

Comment: Jacob, please remove this answer, okay?

Comment: You are forgiven.  Thanks for hanging in with me.  ONWARD THROUGH THE FOG!

Answer (score 1):

I followed Jive Dadson's procedure to get OpenCV2.0 to work on Visual Studio 2010 Express (disabled OMP).
All went good until compilation of the generated stuff in Debug and Release. In both cases got this error: "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '../../lib/Release/cv200.lib'"
in debug the only difference is that the library is cv200d.lib.

EDIT: I solved by downloading the latest svn snapshot for OpenCV2.0. One additional thing on Vista/7: it may be good to execute CMake as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download [OpenCV installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.0/) for Windows
2. Read [OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.Readme.Please.txt](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/2.0/OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.Readme.Please.txt)
3. Follow [OpenCV with Visual C++ 6.0, 2005 Express, and 2008 Express](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B) in order to create project using OpenCV

Comment: As noted elsewhere in this thread, if one is using the free vc++ 2008 Express edition, the instructions in step (2) are not sufficient.  The Express version does not support OpenMP.  When using Cmake to build the project files, it is necessary in that case to UN-check the ENABLE_OPENMP box.