# How to set up OpenCV 2.0 on Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

I am trying to setup OpenCV 2.0 for Visual C++ Express but I can not do it successfully. I have looked all over the internet and have tried the official guide. Can someone guide me to a tutorial that worked for them for OpenCV 2.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32

Comment: @Jacob I already saw that. It is useless.

Comment: And why is that? You have to be more specific.

Comment: @Jacob It helped me to some extent but after one of the stages, it redirects me to the official guide which is back to square one.

Comment: You said you weren't successful in installing it - what happened?

Comment: @Jacob I insalled the directory using cmake and then tried to build the .sln file. It builds and then at the end it asks for the Executable for the Debugging Session but i dont know where it is.

Comment: Omar, you cannot *run* the OpenCV solution. If you chose to add the `Examples` to the build in CMake, then right-click any example from the Solution Explorer, choose `Set as startup project` and then run the program (Ctrl+F5). I recommend `(EXAMPLE) delaunay` since it tests several aspects of OpenCV

Comment: @Jacob I was following this tutorial: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.0/OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.Readme.Please.txt/download?use_mirror=ignum You might understand what I mean then. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: I think you've successfully installed and compiled the libraries. Did you try running an example project?

Comment: I think you should follow the instructions in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32/2273070#2273070 . When you run CMake make sure the `BUILD_EXAMPLES` and `INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES` boxes are checked.

Comment: @Jacob When I build the .sln file, at the end it asks for the Executable for the Debugging session. Can i just ignore this?

Comment: Yes you can ignore this. I think you're trying to run the solution instead of just compiling it. Does this error arise if you just compile it, i.e. hit F7 or Build->Build Solution in the menu bar?

Comment: @Jacob I'll try what you said and i'll get back to you

Comment: @Jacob what does it mean in the tutorial when it says, "build it in Release and Debug configurations".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

Comment: @Jacob When I compiled it as you said, I didn't get that message but will it make a difference because the tutorial says to build it in Release and Debug configurations? Also, can I start coding now?

Comment: It says, "It is important to build both release and debug configurations"

Comment: Yes, so build both release and debug configurations by selecting "Release" and then hitting F7 and "Debug" and then F7. Once that's done, you need to create a **new** solution which links to the libraries you just created and DLLs. Have you used Visual Studio before?

Comment: @Jacob No, not really I haven't used Visual Studio in great depth

Comment: I have [documented](http://andyuk2010.blogspot.com/2011/07/setting-up-opencv-for-visual-studio.html) the process of setting up OpenCV{1.x, 2.x} for Visual Studio environments on my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're done compiling OpenCV, you need to create a new project in Visual C++

1. Click `File->New->Project`.
2. Select `Win32` under `Visual C++` on the left side
3. Select `Win32 Console Application`on the right side
4. Enter a name and click `OK`.
5. Then click `Finish`.

Now, follow the instructions detailed in this tutorial to set the directories etc. It also has a sample program.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B

Let me know if you have any difficulties.

**Update:**
You need to put the folder containing the DLLs in the system path. You can find this folder in the same folder as the `lib` folder which contains `cv200d.lib`. Suppose `cv200d.lib` was in `C:\OpenCV2.0\opencv\lib\debug` then the Debug DLLs should be in `C:\OpenCV2.0\opencv\bin\debug` and the Release DLLs should be in `C:\OpenCV2.0\opencv\bin\release`. If you have any questions about adding folders to the path, let me know.

The above is mentioned in the tutorial you linked to:

> 4 Add the output directories to the system path, e.g.:
>         C:\OpenCV2.0\vs2008\bin\Debug;C:\OpenCV2.0\vs2008\bin\Release:%PATH%
>         It is safe to add both directories, since the Debug
>         OpenCV DLLs have the "d" suffix, which the Release DLLs do not have.

Also, `cv200d.lib` would correctly configure the `Debug` mode of your project. You have to go to the `Release` mode of the project and add `cv200.lib` (i.e. without the `d`).

Comment: I've already seen this tutorial. These instructions are for the older version of OpenCV because the folder structure for OpenCV 2.0 is different. The tutorial I was following, http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.0/OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.Readme.Please.txt/download?use_mirror=ignum, is for OpenCV 2.0. I setup the global options and in page properties I added additional dependancies however, I noticed that instead of putting cv.lib I had to put cv200d.lib etc. After this I tried a program and it said cxcore200d.dll not founf on your computer.

Comment: Great job! So you've got the linker set up properly. Now you need to give your executable access to the DLLs - the simplest way to do this is put the folder containing those DLLs in the system path as an environmental variable - I've included this in my answer.

Comment: @Jacob This must be a silly question but what does the :%PATH% mean in C:\OpenCV2.0\vs2008\bin\Release:%PATH%. When it says Add the output directories I went to create the folder but it was already there. Is there something additional I need to do.

Comment: When adding an environmental variable, does the variable name matter?

Comment: It means the output of the OpenCV solution you compiled. Once you've successfully built OpenCV, the DLLs and LIB files will be stored in the "output directories". The author of the document is just giving you a DOS-like way to set the path - essentially %PATH% means the old path so that the new path is the OpenCV directories + the old path. But you can set the system path through `My Computer` in Windows - do you know how to do that? If not, let me know which OS you're using.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Isn't it System Properties>Advanced System Settings>Environmental Variables and then you add the variable? Does the name matter?

Comment: You don't need to **add** an environmental variable - you need to double-click `Path` in the `System Variables` section and add the paths of the output directories at the end. **DO NOT CHANGE THE OLD PATH IN ANY WAY**

Comment: There was no path in the first place. I had to make one as I had seen in a previous tutorial.

Comment: Suppose the old path is `C:\Foo\Bar;C:\Bar\Foo`, you need to add a `;` and the OpenCV path, i.e. `C:\Foo\Bar;C:\Bar\Foo;C:\OpenCV2.0\vs2008\bin\Release;C:\OpenCV2.0\vs2008\bin\Debug`

Comment: Ok, that's fine - you must be looking at the `User variables for Omar ...`, that'll work as well

Comment: Well, does it work? If so you should really close out the other answers you've created :)

Comment: I was just wondering...
When i was installing OpenCV 2.0 I was given 3 options:

1. Do not add OpenCV to the system PATH
2. Add OpenCV to the system PATH for all users
3. Add OpenCV to the system PATH for current user

Does this have anything to do with the problem. I chose option 1.

Comment: It hasn't worked yet but i'll close my other questions anyways. You've given me more assistance than I would imagine anyone giving me

Comment: No problem! Are you still getting the "DLL not found error"? Ok, try this: find the DLLs you need (they should be in that folder `bin\Debug` and copy them *into the Debug folder of your project`. Do the same for the `bin\Release` folder in OpenCV

Comment: Look at my second last comment. Does this have anything to do with the problem. I'll try what you have said

Comment: It could be, if the above doesn't work, try reinstalling OpenCV with that option and recompiling.

Comment: Finally, it works. I tried a helloworld app and it worked. I owe you a lot Jacob. Thanks for the extensive help.

Comment: Although it works. Is there a way to not have to copy and paste the .dlls every time I start a new project?

Comment: No problem Omar - one way to do that is to set the path. Maybe you should try appending the path of those directories containing the DLLs to the `Path` variable in the `System Variables` box and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jacob Your advice worked! I added two system variables leading to the two sets of .dlls and it works without the copy and pasting. I think i'll make a video tutorial of how to install OpenCV 2.0.0a for Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition and upload it on youtube.

Comment: Haha, great idea, do post a link here so we can check it out later!

Comment: Ok I will do so. By the way, thanks for your time and effort to help me.