# Getting at least one line from Houghline

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Is there an efficient way to guarantee that the houghline method will return at least one line without calling the method again with lower thresholds if there is no line at the first call ?
I mean for example an adaptive thresholds depending on the canny or contoured image which is the input of Hough ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no facility in OpenCV to create an adaptive threshold for HoughLine.

You can however modify OpenCV to return you the vote count for HoughLine in order to allow you to create an adaptive thresholding mechanism of your own. There is a stack overflow post on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352528/opencv-hough-strongest-lines)