# How do we modify OpenCV and generate new DLLs

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

The OpenCV library is great. Most functions have the required functionality, however, I would like to modify some of the functions and recompile so that it fits my specific needs. how would we recompile the dlls and other files? is there a built-in script or do we need to write all the scripts ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [install guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide), you'll need CMake to compile it on Windows.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.aishack.in/2010/03/installing-and-configuring-opencv-2-0-on-windows/) that shows step-by-step how to compile OpenCV 2.0 on Windows, but I believe the instructions also apply for compiling OpenCV 2.1.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32/2273070#2273070) is directly related to what you aim.

Comment: The conclusion I found was to not use the microsoft installer because it sets all these environment variables for you and when you actually want to refer to your new dlls, you get conflicts. I ended up uninstalling opencv and reinstalling using the source code this time. this source code, we can modify as we wish.