# openCV program compiles but crashes on run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, opencv

I just started using openCV (version 2.4.1) in visual studio 2008 on windows 7. I did the installation and the "hello world" program as described in

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B

and

[How to install OpenCV 2.0 on win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32)

Thanks to these instruction my program compiles fine without any errors.  But when I first ran it I got error that files opencv_core241d.dll and tbb_debug.dll are missing.  So obviously something didn't get set right but as per the instruction in first link I copied these files to the same folder where the exe is sitting,  Ran it third time and now I am getting the popup about libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing.  I have done a search on my computer and no such dll is available.

I have researched this online and haven't seen any real solution online about some issues like this.  My guess is with the multiple dll being missing openCV didn;t get installed properly but I have no idea what really is going on.

Any help is desperately needed and will be appreciated heavily by my hairs and scalp.

Comment: Did you set your PATH to include the dir containing the dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps and try.

1. Extract OpenCV 2.4.x into your main partition (I'll assume `C\{opencvdir}`)
2. Add `C\{opencvdir}\build\x86\vc9\bin` to environmental variable's `path` variable. And restart your computer (These settings are for 32bit (x86) Windows version and Visual Studio 2008 (VC9)).
3. Now create a new Visual Studio project and add your sample OpenCV code.
4. Go to project Properties  -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Directories and add:

   ```
   "C\{opencvdir}\include";
   "C\{opencvdir}\include\opencv";
   "C\{opencvdir}\include\opencv2"
   ```
5. Go to project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and add:

   ```
   "C\{opencvdir}\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_core240.lib";
   "C\{opencvdir}\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_highgui240.lib";
   "C\{opencvdir}\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_imgproc240.lib";
   "C\{opencvdir}\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_video240.lib"
   ```

   (These libraries are for a basic application. Add more as your application needs them).
6. Now run your project.

P.S. My recommendation is to use Visual Studio 2010 with OpenCV 2.3.x or higher.

Comment: Perfect step by step instructions.  Had to make small adjustments but otherwise one of the best openCV installation answer.  No need for 10 page installation guide.  Thank you.

Comment: What should be the adjustments..Please list them all.